# Get the index of multiples elements in a haskell list

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

I have a list like `[B,B,N,B,N]` and I want to retrieve all the index of the `N`. So, in this example it would be `[2,4]`.

I don't really know how to do it... I tried with `elemIndex` but in fact I don't think that in my case it's allowed, because that's all the point of the exercise.

I did this for now but I do know that it doesn't work:

```
indice :: [Case] -> [Int]
indice [] = [0]
indice (x:xs)
    | x == N = [1 + head(indice(xs))] ++ indice(xs)
    | x == B = [1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are some problems with your source code: the most important is that the case of `B` and the empty list generate lists with items as well:

```
indice :: [Case] -> [Int]
indice [] = [0]  -- <- list with elements?
indice (x:xs)
    | x == N = [1 + head(indice(xs))] ++ indice(xs)
    | x == B = [1]  -- <- list with elements?
```

Nevertheless, I think for this case you better use an *accumulator*: a variable you update during recursive calls. The accumulator in this case is `i`: the index at which our "*cursor*" is located. We can use an accumulator, by making `indice` call a helper function:

```
indice :: [Case] -> [Int]
indice = helper 0
    where helper --...
```

Now we still need to define our `helper` function.

Furthermore there are three cases we have to take care of:

- we reached the end of the list, in which case we return an empty list as well:

  ```
  helper _ [] = []
  ```
- the cursor is located at an `N`, we "*emit*" the index and make a recursive call updating the index:

  ```
  helper i (N:xs) = i : helper (i+1) xs
  ```
- the cursor is located at another character, we simply move the cursor forward and update the index:

  ```
  helper i (_:xs) = helper (i+1) xs
  ```

Putting it all together, we obtain:

```
indice :: [Case] -> [Int]
indice = helper 0
    where helper _ [] = []
          helper i (N:xs) = i : helper (i+1) xs
          helper i (_:xs) = helper (i+1) xs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the idea to use an accumulator but I did not know how to do it!

Answer (score 3):

You can tag each element with its index using `zip`, filter the elements that match your criteria, and then strip the values, leaving only the indexes:

```
indexesOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
indexesOf v = map fst . filter ((== v) . snd) . zip [0..]
```

So, assuming the type inhabited by `N` and `B` is an instance of `Eq`, you can do:

```
indexesOf N [B,B,N,B,N]
```

and get the answer:

```
[2,4]
```

But, this is just `elemIndices` from `Data.List`